# KDE Connect Not Working [Ubuntu 16.04] : KDE Connect is not discovering phone and vice versa

Tags: linux, firewall, android, port, kde-connect

I have installed the KDE Connect application on my desktop and on my phone [Xiaomi Redmi 3S Prime]. However the desktop application would not detect my phone and vice versa.

I have checked the ports. They are open. There is no firewall installed. I have also tried adding my PC manually by entering the IP address in the Android App and that did not work. I also tried restarting the kdeconnectd daemon, but that also didn't work.

EDIT:
Here are the things that I have tried.

1. Check if the kdeconnectd daemon is running.
   [image]
2. Check if I have the ports blocked and if firewall is enabled.
   [image][image]
3. Check if KDE Connect is listening on the port.
   [image]

Please help with all the solutions you can.

PS. It might seem like a duplicate but I have tried almost all the solutions out there but none of it seems to work for me. Hence, I am here.

Comment: Hi @K7AAY, I have edited the question.

Comment: Adding a bounty to get more exposure.

Comment: Can you post text as text, so that it is readable.

Comment: Yes, please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/18887).

Answer (score 2):

I note that kdeconnect is only listening of IPv6. I had this problem. I don't remember fixing it. I think that kdeconnect is sometimes compiled to use only IPv6.

- Solution will include getting a fixed kdecennect.
- Configuring a local port-forwarder (to listen on this port on IPv4 and forward to IPv6).

Answer (score 2):

I just solve this connection issue with kdeconnect config directory reset, though I still not found IPv4 ...

```bsh
❯ lsof -i | grep kdec
kdeconnec 26104 zzndb   13u  IPv6 424583      0t0  UDP *:xmsg
kdeconnec 26104 zzndb   15u  IPv6 424584      0t0  TCP *:xmsg (LISTEN)
kdeconnec 26104 zzndb   27u  IPv6 697149      0t0  TCP 192.168.0.110:45944->192.168.0.115:xmsg (ESTABLISHED)
```

The reset detail maybe as following:

- kill kdeconnectd with `killall kdeconnectd`
- backup old direcotry with `mv ~/.config/kdeconnect{,_bak}`
- start kdeconnectd with `nohup /the/path/to/your/kdeconnectd &>/dev/null &`

Once you can connect to your device, you can recovery the config file from old bak directory such as `kdeconnect_runcommand/config`.

Answer (score 2):

Open port ranges `1714:1764/udp` and `1714:1764/tcp`

If you use `ufw`:

- in `/etc/ufw/applications.d/`, create file text named `kdeconnect` and add

  ```ini
  [kdeconnect]

  title=KDE Connect
  description=Device Synchronization
  ports=1714:1764/udp|1714:1764/tcp
  ```
- in console, run

  ```shell
  sudo ufw allow kdeconnect
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue, and was convinced no firewall was running on my machine as the ports where not being blocked, however, came across this [KDE doc](https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect#I_have_two_devices_running_KDE_Connect_on_the_same_network.2C_but_they_can.27t_see_each_other) with instructions to open the firewall for various linux packages and realised `firewalld` was actually running, so the following worked for me:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=kdeconnect
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

- First your router may isolate communication between devices for security.
- Check that you phone is using ipv6 as well. (as your computer seems to use ipv6)
- Try to ping the computer from the phone and then ping the phone from the computer
- Also make sure the computer and the phone are connected on the same network

Once you fix the communication between the devices and check that they are using the same protocol on the same wifi network it should be fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Going by your Ubuntu version, your KDE connect version should be [0.8](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/kde/kdeconnect). But, if it is 1.0, then there is a chance that the problem is either:

- [fixed in version 1.0.3 of KDE connect](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371539#c31), or
- [an issue with bindist flag of openssl](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8048756.html?sid=3837ce396688a2a9b9b1745c983f3dcc#8048756)

An alternate workaround maybe [disabling ipv6 altogether](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=371539#c26).